# cannot stat ' file name ': No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell

Hi I have written a code which is writing a file with .out extension in python script.
and I am trying to copy the same file to waiting folder as below:

```
Variables:
-------------------
BASE_DIR = BASE_DIR='/proj/ctc/temp/sanjay/REC-754'
STAGE_DIR=$BASE_DIR/staging
FEED_FILE=`ls -p $STAGE_DIR | grep -v /` 
OUT_FILE=`ls -p $STAGE_DIR | grep -v /`.out
DISCARD_FILE=`ls -p $STAGE_DIR | grep -v /`.discard
........
.......

chmod +x $BASE_DIR/CsvReader_1.py
python $BASE_DIR/CsvReader_1.py $1 $FEED_FILE $DISCARD_FILE $OUT_FILE >output.txt 2>&1 &


log 'Copying the Out File without .out extension to CTC Waiting directory.'

CTC_WAIT_FILE=`echo $OUT_FILE|sed -e 's/\.out//'`
echo $CTC_WAIT_FILE
cp $OUT_FILE $CTC_WAITING_DIR/$CTC_WAIT_FILE
chmod 776 $CTC_WAITING_DIR/$CTC_WAIT_FILE
```

**But I am getting below Error**

```
    cp: cannot stat `2017-05-29_IR_Position_Report_US_US_2017-05-30.csv.out': No such file or directory
    chmod: cannot access `2017-05-29_IR_Position_Report_US_US_2017-05-30.csv': No such file or directory
```

But I can see clearly that file exists there.
I have attached the screenshot of the winscp and clearly file can be seen there.

please help me , thanks in advance.

Comment: `ls` is not a trustworthy way to retrieve filenames for programmatic use. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Also, `echo $foo` is not guaranteed to represent the contents of variable `foo` accurately. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: ...might I suggest that if this is intended to be used from a Python script, you write it in Python, not in shell?

Comment: (Also, all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the shell or operating system, whereas lower-case names are reserved for application use; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable).

Comment: ...also, run this all through http://shellcheck.net/, and fix what it finds.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following:

```
cd ~/proj/ctc/temp/sanjay/REC-754
pwd
```

I'm willing to bet `pwd` returns  `/home/username/proj/ctc/temp/sanjay/REC-754` and not `/proj/ctc/temp/sanjay/REC-754`

`~` is replaced by the user home directory.